# Inline Function, Column names in each view or function must be unique

Tags: sql-server, inline-table-function

I have join the two table and now i want to save that statement in function so that I can use that again 
  and again. I tried to create the function as follow:-

```
create function fn_electricalsem1and2()
returns table
as
return (
      Select * 
      from [Electrical Semester 1 Regular] as T1 
      inner join[Electrical Semester 2 Regular] As T2 On T1.department_id= T2.department_id
)
```

Now I am getting error

> Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name
>   'Name' in view or function 'fn_electricalsem1and2' is specified more
>   than once.

I haven't made any function till now but why am I getting error function must be unique?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) - As an aside, if this function is going to be parameterless then it may make more sense as a view rather than a function. Either way though, you will need to be explicit about the columns you want to return rather than using `SELECT *`.

Comment: A few more bad habits that you may wish to kick - [using dashes and spaces in entity names](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-dashes-and-spaces-in-entity-names) - [using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3), [avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is giving error because your function is returning a table and in a table all the column name should be unique.

To solve the issue you need to replace

```
Select *
```

To

```
Select t1.column1 as Col1, t1.column2, t2.column1 as Col2, ...and so on
```

In your case `department_id` is available in both the tables. Also both table contains a column of name: `name`.

Comment: My Select statement is correct and it works too but my main problem is I can't create the function

Comment: @Awesome I am saying that use alias and the column name while creating the function as t1.name as t1name, t2.name as t2Name, etc. It is giving error because function is returning a table and in the table all column name should be unique.

Comment: @Awesome I think the select statement returns the result set not the table so in select it does not give the error even if more than one column with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

In the following query, 
we will create the tables at first and populate them some data.

```
CREATE TABLE [Electrical Semester 1 Regular](department_id INT);
CREATE TABLE [Electrical Semester 2 Regular](department_id INT);
INSERT INTO [Electrical Semester 1 Regular]
VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO [Electrical Semester 2 Regular]
VALUES(1);
```

When we execute the following query you will not experience any error ;

```
 Select * 
 from [Electrical Semester 1 Regular] as T1 
      inner join[Electrical Semester 2 Regular] As T2 On T1.department_id= T2.department_id

+---------------+---------------+
| department_id | department_id |
+---------------+---------------+
|             1 |             1 |
+---------------+---------------+
```

However, the following query returns an error because of the same column names of the **[Electrical Semester 1 Regular]** and **[Electrical Semester 2 Regular]**. In the SQL Server if we want to create a view or function we have to give unique names with alias

```
create function fn_electricalsem1and2()
returns table
as
return (
      Select * 
      from [Electrical Semester 1 Regular] as T1 
      inner join[Electrical Semester 2 Regular] As T2 On T1.department_id= T2.department_id
)
```

In the SQL Server if we want to create a view or function we have to give unique names. You enable it with an alias so you can change your query like the below;

```
create function fn_electricalsem1and2()
returns table
as
return (
      Select t1.department_id as t1_department_id , t2.department_id as t2_department_id
      from [Electrical Semester 1 Regular] as T1 
      inner join[Electrical Semester 2 Regular] As T2 On T1.department_id= T2.department_id
)

GO
select * from fn_electricalsem1and2()


    +------------------+------------------+
    | t1_department_id | t2_department_id |
    +------------------+------------------+
    |                1 |                1 |
    +------------------+------------------+
```